# CORS error when using elasticsearch.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, cors

I am trying to test an index from my local machine. I created a simple HTML page with a query box that sends the query to ES using the elasticsearch.js client. Both the index and the browser are on my desktop, so there shouldn't be a cross origin problem, but I keep getting an error that states:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9200/portal/book/_search?q=title%3Ahistoire. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9200/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I tried enabling CORS, but get the same error. Here are the index's settings:

```
{
    "portal": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1421788614558",
                "uuid": "jg-iHjnSTDGHODY0_x4Ysw",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "http": {
                    "cors": {
                        "enabled": "true",
                        "allow-origin": "/(http://)?localhost(:[0-9]+)?/"
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "version": {
                    "created": "1040299"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="portal">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <span class="span3">
                    <input class="input-block-level" ng-model="queryTerm" type="text">
                </span>&nbsp;
                <button ng-click="search()" class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                Found {{ results.hits.total }}
                <div class="span4">
                    <li ng-repeat="doc in results.hits.hits">
                        {{ doc._source.title }}
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('portal', [
    'controllers',
]);

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    apiVersion: '1.3',

});
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('controllers', []).controller('SearchCtrl',
    function($scope) {

        $scope.search = function(query) {
            $scope.results = client.search({
                    index: 'portal',
                    type: 'book',
                    q: 'title:' + $scope.queryTerm
                }, function (error, response) {console.log('could not execute query!')}
            );
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Is the client side and backend on the same domains?

Comment: Yes, I'm running both on my desktop.

Comment: Does the elasticsearch.js client add any custom headers?

Answer (score 3):

Add following line to your config yml file

```
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

and kill elastic search java process on unix based system like is demonstrated on this topic response https://stackoverflow.com/a/41644614/11079315

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are getting a cross domain error to begin with. Are you opening your front end as file://.... ? Totally random guess and not sure it matters. If you are and want to run your UI through a web server, you can open a terminal, cd into that dir and run 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7000'. Now your UI is running on localhost:7000.

For CORS settings, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html and, if you are using Chrome, http://www.williamjohnbert.com/2013/06/allow-cors-with-localhost-in-chrome/ might help.

In your config you should at least set 'http.cors.enabled: true' and 'http.cors.allow-credentials: true'. The other defaults should be sensible. You may also want to modify the 'http.cors.max-age' setting in case old settings are cached.

Use the js console, net tab in your browser to see what headers you are getting back.

Comment: I added 'http.cors.enabled: true' and 'http.cors.allow-credentials: true' to my elasticsearch.yml and that's works. thank you.