# Elasticsearch, Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch won't start using `./bin/elasticsearch`.
It raises the following exception:

```
- ElasticsearchIllegalStateException[Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [/home/user1/elasticsearch-1.4.4/data/elasticsearch]
```

I checked the permissions on the same location and the location has 777 permissions on it and is owned by user1.

```
ls -al /home/user1/elasticsearch-1.4.4/data/elasticsearch
```

> ```
> drwxrwxrwx  3 user1 wheel 4096 Mar  8 13:24 .
> drwxrwxrwx  3 user1 wheel 4096 Mar  8 13:00 ..
> drwxrwxrwx 52 user1 wheel 4096 Mar  8 13:51 nodes
> ```

What is the problem?

Trying to run elasticsearch 1.4.4 on linux without root access.

Comment: I also got this error message with a fresh new debian elasticsearch 1.4.4 installation. A simple reboot helped to make this message dissappear.

Answer (score 117):

I had an orphaned Java process related to Elasticsearch. Killing it solved the lock issue.

```
ps aux | grep 'java'
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: This applies to Dockerized Elasticsearch also. My host was not showing any Elasticsearch containers, but it seems the last daemon restart left the host process orphaned, without even showing at `docker ps -a`. This fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 30):

I got this same error message, but things were mounted fine and the permissions were all correctly assigned.

Turns out that I had an 'orphaned' elasticsearch process that was not being killed by the normal stop command.

I had to manually kill the process and then restarting elasticsearch worked again.

Answer (score 29):

the reason is another instance is running!
first find the id of running elastic.

```
ps aux | grep 'elastic'
```

then kill using `kill -9 <PID_OF_RUNNING_ELASTIC>`.
There were some answers to remove node.lock file but that didn't help since the running instance will make it again!

Comment: Perfect. Somehow I had 2 instances caught by the `grep`.

Answer (score 19):

In my situation I had wrong permissions on the ES dir folder. Setting correct owner solved it.

```
# change owner
chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /data/elasticsearch/

# to validate
ls /data/elasticsearch/ -la
# prints    
# drwxr-xr-x 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Apr 30 14:54 CLUSTER_NAME
```

Comment: On OSX, with brew, the node locks are files written somewhere under `/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/nodes` If you had an old ElasticSearch sitting around like I did, you can start by either trying to delete a specific `node.lock` file or go nuclear and `rm -rf` the `nodes` folder.

Answer (score 12):

After I upgraded the elasticsearch docker-image from version 5.6.x to 6.3.y the container would not start anymore because of the aforementioned error

> Failed to obtain node lock

In my case the root-cause of the error was **missing file-permissions**

The data-folder used by elasticsearch was mounted from the host-system into the container (declared in the docker-compose.yml):

```
    volumes:
      - /var/docker_folders/common/experimental-upgrade:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

This folder could not be accessed anymore by elasticsearch for reasons I did not understand at all. After I set very permissive file-permissions to this folder and all sub-folders **the container did start again**.

I do not want to reproduce the command to set those very permissive access-rights on the mounted docker-folder, because it is most likely a very bad practice and a security-issue. I just wanted to share the fact that it might not be a second process of elasticsearch running, but actually just missing access-rights to the mounted folder.

Maybe someone could elaborate on the apropriate rights to set for a mounted-folder in a docker-container?

Answer (score 8):

As with many others here replying, this was caused by wrong permissions on the directory (not owned by the elasticsearch user). In our case it was caused by uninstalling Elasticsearch and reinstalling it (via yum, using the official repositories).

As of this moment, the repos do not delete the `nodes` directory when they are uninstalled, but they do delete the `elasticsearch` user/group that owns it. So then when Elasticsearch is reinstalled, a new, different `elasticsearch` user/group is created, leaving the old `nodes` directory still present, but owned by the old UID/GID. This then conflicts and causes the error.

A recursive chown as mentioned by @oleksii is the solution.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and well-written answer.  In my case, `chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes` was called for.  I had also uninstalled and reinstalled kibana, with the result that I needed to run `chown -R kibana:kibana /var/lib/kibana` for a similar reason.

Answer (score 5):

You already have ES running.  To prove that type:

curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

If you want to run another instance on the same box you can set node.max_local_storage_nodes in elasticsearch.yml to a value larger than 1.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:
1. find the port 9200, e.g.: `lsof -i:9200`
   This will show you which processes use the port 9200.
2. kill the pid(s), e.g. repeat `kill -9 pid` for each PID that the output of `lsof` showed in step 1
3. restart elasticsearch, e.g. `elasticsearch`

Answer (score 4):

check these options

```
sudo chown 1000:1000 <directory you wish to mount>
# With docker
sudo chown 1000:1000 /data/elasticsearch/ 
OR
# With VM
sudo chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch /data/elasticsearch/
```

Answer (score 3):

I had an another ElasticSearch running on the same machine.

Command to check : ***netstat -nlp | grep 9200*** (9200 - Elastic Port)
Result : tcp        0      0 :::9210                     :::*       LISTEN      27462/java

Kill the process by,
***kill -9 27462***
27462 - PID of ElasticSearch instance

Start the elastic search and it may run now.

Comment: Thanks. Onn a centos7.x , my OS partition mounted for ES data were at 100% due to poor system maintenance (growing indices not pruned or archived offline). ES stopped working. On clearing the directory and rebooting, the error "..org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried" came up. The solution was identifying the old ES pid and killing it. before restart.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the `/var/lib/elasticsearch` was the dir with missing permissions (CentOS 8):

> error: java.io.IOException: failed to obtain lock on /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0

To fix it, use:

```sh
chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this error was caused by not mounting the devices used for the configured data directories using "sudo mount".

Answer (score 2):

chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch

It directly shows it doesn't have permission to obtain a lock. So need to give permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this error occurs when you kill the process abruptly. When you kill the process, node.lock file may not be cleared. you can manually remove the node.lock file and start the process again, it should work

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answers there could be some other scenarios in which you can get the error.In fact I had done a update from 5.5 to 6.3 for elasticsearch.I have been using the docker compose setup with named volumes for data directories.I had to do a `docker volume prune` to remove the stale ones.After doing that I was no longer facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is seeing this being caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/docker/es]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
```

The solution is to set `max_local_storage_nodes` in your elasticsearch.yml

```
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2
```

[The docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#max-local-storage-nodes) say to set this to a number greater than one on your development machine

> By default, Elasticsearch is configured to prevent more than one node from sharing the same data path. To allow for more than one node (e.g., on your development machine), use the setting node.max_local_storage_nodes and set this to a positive integer larger than one.

I think that Elasticsearch needs to have a second node available so that a new instance can start.  This happens to me whenever I try to restart Elasticsearch inside my Docker container.  If I relaunch my container then Elasticsearch will start properly the first time without this setting.

Comment: Just for the record: I try ECK 2.2 + ES 8.2.3 and run into the same error message "not writeable on the same data path" Likely root cause: NosuckFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/node.lock

Comment: This might be useful as a clue https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-obtain-node-locks-tried-usr-share-elasticsearch-data-with-lock-id-0/205706/6

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows then try this:

1. Kill any java processes
2. If the start batch is interrupted in between then rather than closing the terminal, press `ctrl+c` to properly stop the elastic search service before you exit the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
mkdir -p ./elasticsearch/docs
mkdir -p ./elasticsearch/logs
chmod -R 777 ./elasticsearch
```

*where `elasticsearch` is your docker volume directory on host machine*

Check https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/96601#issuecomment-1580384744

Is solution for me.

Comment: maybe actually It just needed the permissions. idk. cuz' I had troubles creating `logs` dir on my non-root user

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was a simple one: I created a new data directory /mnt/elkdata and changed the ownership to the elastic user. I then copied the files and forgot to change the ownership afterwards again.

After doing that and restarting the elastic node it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (docker on windows) I solved it by temporarily changing mapped volume source path:

1. Change mapped path for docker container
   i.e. from

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./artifacts/elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

to

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./artifacts/elasticsearch-data1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

2. `docker compose down && docker compose up --wait -d` or any other way to recreate containers.
3. Delete source path `./artifacts/elasticsearch-data`. Just in case.
4. change path back to original

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./artifacts/elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

5. one more time recreate containers

Other ways didn't work for me. I tried to delete folder, prune volumes, delete all containers, restarting docker, restarting PC, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a problem while deploying Elasticsearch using Helm on a Minikube cluster with two or more nodes. The issue arises when the second node fails to access a directory that is already locked by the first node. Unfortunately, at the current state, Minikube does not provide a built-in solution to resolve this problem.

To mitigate this issue, I recommend deploying Elasticsearch on Minikube using a single node configuration. By using a single node, you can avoid conflicts related to directory locking. Here's the recommended approach:

1. Start Minikube with the specified profile (`multinode-demo` in this case) using the following command:

   ```
   minikube start -p multinode-demo
   ```

   This command initializes Minikube with a single node, eliminating the contention between multiple nodes that causes the directory access issue.

By deploying Elasticsearch on a single node in Minikube, you ensure that the directory locking problem is circumvented. Although this solution may not provide the full benefits of a multi-node cluster, it allows for successful deployment and operation of Elasticsearch in a development or testing environment.

Please note that this solution is specific to the issue described and the context of deploying Elasticsearch on Minikube. In a production or high-availability scenario, it is advisable to use a proper multi-node Kubernetes cluster with appropriate distributed storage solutions to ensure the resilience and scalability of your Elasticsearch deployment.

I hope this information helps in resolving the problem you encountered with Elasticsearch deployments on Minikube.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since both of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.