# Problems running Elasticsearch 1.7.1 on Bash for Windows

Tags: windows, bash, elasticsearch

I am trying to run Elasticsearch 1.7.1 on Bash for Windows. 
This is the error I am getting:

```
user@SOME-PC:~/elasticsearch-1.7.1$ ./bin/elasticsearch
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (common).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[2016-12-01 00:15:07,945][INFO ][node                     ] [Zach] version[1.7.1], pid[1719], build[b88f43f/2015-07-29T09:54:16Z]
[2016-12-01 00:15:07,946][INFO ][node                     ] [Zach] initializing ...
[2016-12-01 00:15:08,027][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Zach] loaded [], sites []
{1.7.1}: Initialization Failed ...
- ElasticsearchIllegalStateException[Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [/home/user/elasticsearch-1.7.1/data/elasticsearch]]
        IOException[failed to obtain lock on /home/user/elasticsearch-1.7.1/data/elasticsearch/nodes/49]
                IOException[Mount point not found]
```

Java version:

```
user@SOME-PC:~/elasticsearch-1.7.1$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Ubuntu version:

```
user@SOME-PC:~/elasticsearch-1.7.1$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Come on guys, at least tell why you are down-voting!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a permission issue, in order to access your node. Try giving the permission to the owner as per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932178/elasticsearch-failed-to-obtain-node-lock-is-the-following-location-writable).

> chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /data/elasticsearch/

You might want to have a look at this [ticket](https://github.com/dockerfile/elasticsearch/issues/42) as well.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the links you mentioned before, but the thing is I do not have the elasticsearch user. Not sure at what point it is created. Should I add it by myself?

Comment: @SM79 Yes you have to add the permission.