# Unable to Start ElasticSearch with Public IP instead of localhost

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to start elastic search with private ip address but it does not get started it shows some errors in error log which i have shared below.

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#Also Tried with Private IP Address   network.host: 52.50.122.93

#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["52.50.122.93", "127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

**elasticsearch.log**

```
[2019-05-21T17:22:28,068][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [WIN-CQKBIA6F350] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[C:\ELKStack\elasticsearch-7.1.0\data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:325) [elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) [elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) [elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) [elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
[2019-05-21T17:22:28,085][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [WIN-CQKBIA6F350] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[C:\ELKStack\elasticsearch-7.1.0\data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[C:\ELKStack\elasticsearch-7.1.0\data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set one of these values 
[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

ex discovery.seed_hosts:
   - 192.168.1.10:9300
   - 192.168.1.11 
   - seeds.mydomain.com

Comment: where do i set abobe things?

Comment: In elastic search folder> config>elasticsearch.yml. Uncomment below line  #discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]. You need to provide your own ip address. You can also either set cluster.initial_master_nodes which will be ip of your server

Comment: Is this configuration correct - cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]. If yes can you look at below link it has discussion for error in log file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932178/elasticsearch-failed-to-obtain-node-lock-is-the-following-location-writable/43163772

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear in the log file

```
the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
```

You have to set the *cluster.initial_master_node* or *discovery.seed_hosts* setting
Also don't forget to set the *node.name* and the *cluster.name*, you can also start ES and set the master node with this command-line:

```
bin/elasticsearch -Ecluster.initial_master_nodes=master-a,master-b,master-c
```

---

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/important-settings.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/discovery-settings.html